# clockworkmod/backup can it be removed?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note

Today I installed cyanogenmod JB on my galaxy note and I found this huge directory (2.47GB) in the /sdcard partition. Can it be removed or it could be useful? Can I move it on my pc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two times yes: Of course it can be removed, and of course it can be useful. At that place ClockworkMod stores the [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backups you've created with it, and from that place you can restore them when need for that arrives.

In case of an external SDCard, and when space on it is precious to you, you could simply copy its contents to your computer, and then empty the directory. Or just keep the latest backup on it. If you need to restore one of the removed backups, it then would be possible to use a card reader, copy them back, and re-insert the card to your device so they can be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into recovery and check how the "/sdcard" is mounted using the command "mount". If it is not mounted, you can mount it and should be able to get rid of this directory using "rm -rf"(however, you might like to check the significance of this data first). If it is mounted as read-only, remount it with "rw" option and go for deletion.

As for moving it to the PC, "/sdcard" is usually visible when the device is connected to Windows(Underlying partition is usually formatted with FAT). Have you already tried that?

Comment: I was talking about /sdcard/clockworkmode/backup directory